# upgrading to .net 6.0 and getting error in runtime method not found -Microsoft.EntityFramework.Infrasturcture.Iannotable.FindAnnotation(system.String)

Tags: .net-6.0

upgrading to .net 6.0 and getting below error in runtime

System.missingmethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFramework.Infrastructure.Iannotation
Microsoft.EntityFramework.Infrasturcture.Iannotable.FindAnnotation(system.String)

It appears to be a breaking change? if so how to fix this issue.

Comment: Upgrading from what version? Did you also update EF? Show the package you're using? (Yes there constanly are changes. E.g. there's a big difference between EF and EFCore).

Comment: upgrading from .netcore3.0 to .net 6.0. I have updated related EF core versions to 6.0.0 too but failing with this error.

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Infrastructure` isn't an EF Core namespace. Were you using EF 6.2 or EF Core 3 before the upgrade?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that is a typo (there are multiple typos actually). There is no `IAnnotation` in EF non-core. Actually, the whole namespace for EF6 is `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: Oh: by the way did you delete the bin and obj directories after the upgrade? Usually highly advised when updating to a new dotnet version. And are all dependent projects also up to date?

Answer (score 0):

It seems [FindAnnotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.annotatable.findannotation?view=efcore-5.0) was moved in EF Core 6.0 to  [IReadOnlyAnnotable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.ireadonlyannotatable.findannotation?view=efcore-6.0) interface.

There constantly are major changes between versions. You can find the most critical ones on pages like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes).